# How to use AirFlow to run a folder of python files?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a series of Python tasks inside a folder of python files: file1.py, file2.py, ...

I read the Airflow docs, but I don't see how to specify the folder and filename of the python files in the DAG?

I would like to execute those python files (not the Python function through Python Operator).

Task1:  Execute file1.py   (with some import package)

Task2:  Execute file2.py   (with some other import package)

It would be helpful. Thanks, regards

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use BashOperator to execute python files as a task

```
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators import BashOperator,PythonOperator
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                      datetime.min.time())

    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': seven_days_ago,
        'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
      )

    dag = DAG('simple', default_args=default_args)
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='testairflow',
    bash_command='python /home/airflow/airflow/dags/scripts/file1.py',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: Why do you import PythonOperator here? You don't seem to use it.

Comment: @beten Keep it light! but yes good catch

Answer (score 22):

I know you're asking that you "would like to execute those python files (not the Python function through Python Operator)." but I see this as probably using Airflow less effectively than you could be. I also see confusion in the previously written answers so here's the way you wanted, and the way I'd recommend to do the tasks:

Assuming:

```
dags/
    my_dag_for_task_1_and_2.py
    tasks/
         file1.py
         file2.py
```

Your request to avoid the `PythonOperator`:

```
#  my_dag_for_task_1_and_2.py
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator

with DAG(
    'my_dag_for_task_1_and_2',
    default_args={
        'owner': 'me',
        'start_date': datetime(…),
        …,
    }, 
    schedule_interval='8 * * * *',
) as dag:
    task_1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task_1', 
        bash_command='/path/to/python /path/to/dags/tasks/file1.py',
    )
    task_2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task_2', 
        bash_command='/path/to/python /path/to/dags/tasks/file2.py',
    )
    task_1 >> task_2
```

You didn't write the Python from scratch for Airflow, but with `PythonOperator`:

```
#  my_dag_for_task_1_and_2.py
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
import tasks.file1
import tasks.file2

with DAG(
    'my_dag_for_task_1_and_2',
    default_args={
        'owner': 'me',
        'start_date': datetime(…),
        …,
    }, 
    schedule_interval='8 * * * *',
) as dag:
    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_1', 
        python_callable=file1.function_in_file1,
    )
    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_2', 
        python_callable=file2.function_in_file2,  # maybe main?
    )
    task_1 >> task_2
```

Comment: I like that you use `with DAG(...) as dag: ...`. Improves context.

Comment: @Wordsmyth the community is working on updating all the examples to show a mix of all the different ways to specify tasks in a DAG and task dependencies. So this will hopefully become a less "hidden" feature soon.

Comment: @dlamblin, the way you are importing, I tried the similar way, but my DAG is not recognizing it. 
I have created folder called scripts inside dag, and kept my file inside scripts.
import scripts.file1

Comment: @AshishKumar you probably need to put an `__init__.py` file inside the scripts folder. It can be empty. Refer to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @dlamblin Following your answer, I get the error tasks module is not found. I have included an empty __init__.py file, as suggested above. Any idea?

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás it would be sensitive to the directory and file layout; here the `tasks` directory with `__init__.py` in it is at the top level of the DAGs folder. Airflow adds that folder to the `PYTHONPATH` if you made it a subfolder you'd need to include the module path all the way to the file, like `subfolder.tasks.file1` which implies another `__init__.py` in each parent folder (and possibly the DAG folder itself).

Answer (score 20):

To execute the python file as a whole, using the `BashOperator` (As in liferacer's answer):

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_task',
    bash_command='python file1.py',
    dag=dag
)
```

Then, to do it using the `PythonOperator` call your `main` function.  You should already have a `__main__` block, so put what happens in there into a `main` function, such that your `file1.py` looks like so:

```
def main():
    """This gets executed if `python file1` gets called."""
    # my code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then your dag definition:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

import file1

python_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_task',
    python_callable=file1.main,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: The `bash_task = PythonOperator` and the `… bash_operator import PythonOperator` are pretty confusing and likely an error.

Comment: Shouldn't your first block of code use `BashOperator` and not `PythonOperator`?

Comment: Thanks. calling module.main is necessary especially when you call remote function on ipython. otherwise you get error like unusual_prefix_dac28c52b432fb881bf6fa1c4f25b4960b7ffe5a_ipython_dag.